# Seting the number of executors for my Spark Streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am runnning my Spark Streaming application in the Yarn cluster mode. I want to limit the number of executors to just one node? How to do this in Spark?

Comment: Your question is little bit confusing. Do you wants to control the number of executors or the execution of all executors on single node only?

Comment: No I wnat to have just one executor and one driver

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of executors by two ways:

**`Option 1:`** Directly with Spark Submit Command:

```
spark-submit -class ClassName --num-executors 1 .... other parameters
```

**`Option 2:`** Inside Conf flag with Spark Submit command:

```
spark-submit --class ClassName --conf "spark.executor.instances=1" .... other parameters.
```

You can get more detailed information about the same from [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).